# Object association: Which object should reference the other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, agile

Here's a task that is common to the kind of website we produce but I'm not sure on the best way of designing the classes. Being fairly new to agile development I want to ensure I avoid picking up bad habits.

I am working on a website that contains a page for each of several countries. The CMS allows users to change the content for each country page (title, copy etc.) We have been asked if the timetables (downloadable PDFs) can be managed by the CMS.

Assuming I have a Country class and a Timetable class what's the best (from an agile perspective)?

1. Create a property in the country class:

`public List<Timetable> Timetables`

1. Create a property in the Timetable class:

`public Country AssignedCountry`

Surely though, what's best is determined by how the info is used. As mentioned there is a page of each country that will display timetables for that country. However, there's also a timetable page that lists all timetables and, ideally, shows the country they are for.

Using option 1 means the country page can easily list it's timetables but each timetable on the timetable page has no reference the country it's assigned to.

Option 2 means the timetable page is easier as I can list all timetables and show the associated country. However, the country page is more awkward because each country has no idea about it's timetables so some other method is required to get relevant timetables.

Option 3?
Since timetables aren't really a property of a country and likewise, country is not a property of a PDF file, I'm thinking I may be better off creating a static utility class (factory?) that contains methods I can call to get me the info I need - timetables by country or countries by timetable. The country/timetable relationship in the DB is many-to-many so this seems the more logical solution.

Our clients usually want to add more functionality to the CMS and normally it's not an issue to decide how things are related but this kind of thing bugs me.

Am I overcomplicating things? Is there a simple, rule of thumb or technique I'm missing?

Comment: Option 3 with a Repository class...

Comment: Why do you keep repeating "agile" in your question? Object design has nothing to do with an agile development methodology.

Comment: Well, I mentioned it twice - hardly kept repeating it. Anyway, I would have thought agile principles and patterns do have something to do with how you design objects and their associations.

Comment: +1 for Repository class. I hadn't come across this pattern before, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to a couple of simple questions...

- does each timetable apply only to a single country?
- does each timetable have to be associated with a country, or can they be free-floating?

If each timetable must be associated with a single country, I'd be tempted to put the country id in the timetable object and select from sql with a join for display.  If the answer is different, you should consider the full use cases for these objects, and that should define your answer for you.

Comment: I'm guessing timetables will be assigned to multiple countries (as Germany to France could be shown on the France and Germany page).

Comment: I also expect the client to want to manage timetables that are not assigned and thus free floating. (BTW, I have to go through account managers to get info from the client and they don't know what they want half the time hence the need to keep it flexible and extensible yet robust).

Comment: Then it sounds like option 2 is your default starting position.  Option 2 wouldn't work as you only have the option to assign a single country.  However you shouldn't rule out denormalising out to a third "CountryTimetable"  table to handle the association.  That would give you more flexibility at the expense of slightly more complex dtaa read/write logic.

Comment: The options I listed aren't set in stone so option 2 could actually be a `List<Country>` to have it assigned to 0-* countries and I haven't ruled out a many-to-many table to handle the relationships. However, as it's managed by a CMS where many bits of content inherit a generic "chunk" class (for common properties/methods) and a static manager class to read/write these "chunks" to the DB I would like to try and use the code already written.

Comment: I also have to consider security access in the CMS - someone assigned to manage the timetables will be required to assign them to countries hence the thinking that option 2 may be better. I suppose though, that even though the country ref could be assigned to the timetables there's nothing to stop me adding a GetTimetables() method to the country class. "Where there is choice, there is misery" :)

Comment: I agree the use cases should help determine where the association is so I'll add it to the Timetable class. I can then add a GetByCountry() method to my timetable manager class. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree that option 1 and option 2 are not the best for you.
Probably the best choice is to use a database and read with a third class what you need.

Surely you can also use option 1 and 2 together.

In Country you know what Timetable to show, in Timetable you know what Country can show it.

Also you can force the use of one of the two options, but doing so you need at least a list of Country in an List, when you have a timetable you cycle all the Country asking "isValidTimetable" and then you have all the country that can show the Timetable.

But all this depends on how many objects you have, thing that you don't tell us.

Comment: Combining option 1 and 2 would seem logical. If a many-to-many table can be queried to get timetables by country or countries by timetable then it would be cool to have some static object also do the same thing. It would mean the country and timetable classes are decoupled but extra code required to handle the relationship between the two (which I have no prob with if it's "better" moving forward).

Comment: Just two in this particular situation: Country class and Timetable class. Obviously though I can add more if required but I don't want to pre-empt what may be needed in the future (YAGNI :)) but need to keep it modular enough to extend in future if necessary.

Comment: i mean how many country and timetables total you have, if we are talking about small numbers it's ok, but if you have thousand of types the thing is harder..

Comment: There's currently about 7 countries. The client will be able to use the CMS to create/upload timetable PDFs and assign them to one or more countries so I would expect no more than a few timetables to be assigned per country.